# 301 редирект с .html на /

Tags: wordpress, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение для 301 редиректа

Нужно урлы которые заканчиваются на **.html** редиректить на **/**

например:

- [https://site.сom.au/categoryname/post-name.html](https://site.xn--om-nmc.au/categoryname/post-name.html)
- [https://site.сom.au/categorynames/post-name-name.html](https://site.xn--om-nmc.au/categorynames/post-name-name.html)
- [https://site.сom.au/topic-name/post.html](https://site.xn--om-nmc.au/topic-name/post.html)

редиректить на:

- [https://site.сom.au/categoryname/post-name/](https://site.xn--om-nmc.au/categoryname/post-name/)
- [https://site.сom.au/categorynames/post-name-name/](https://site.xn--om-nmc.au/categorynames/post-name-name/)
- [https://site.сom.au/topic-name/post/](https://site.xn--om-nmc.au/topic-name/post/)

то есть все что заканчивается на ***.html** редиректить так, чтобы заканчивалось на ***/**

спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

в .htaccess нужно прописать

`RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: вроде в вопросе нет ничего ни про apache, ни про его эпический костыль под название htaccess.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  wp универсальный он и с apache и с nginx без apache работает https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Comment: кхм. я именно на это вам и намекал.